# Avoid cyclic references

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm building a small game with SDL. I've a class `GameObject` which is the main class for representing objects in my game. The different behaviors are solved my components you can inject from the outside:

```
#include "Input.h"
class GameObject
{
public:
    void setInput(Input* input)
    {
        input->setGameObject(this);
        this->input = input;
    }
}


class GameObject; // cannot #include "GameObject.h"
class Input
{
private:
    GameObject* object;
public:
    void update(float elapsedTime)
    {
        // do fancy stuff on the GameObject object
    }
    void setGameObject(GameObject* object)
    {
        this->object = object;
    }
}
```

The `Input` class has to work on the `GameObject` instance. I have a cyclic reference now which is not a good idea I guess?

Edit: I adjusted my example to make it clearer. I have some of these components like the `Input` class and I've to use this `class GameObject;` statement since I cannot include the header file.
So if I understood it correctly I've a cyclic reference!? To solve that I would have to use an interface and add this to `setGameObject(InputInterface* object)`. But I cannot predict what functions/member are needed for access of the `GameObject` because there are different components used (e.g. `PlayerInput`, `DemoInput`, `AiInput`, ...).

Comment: From what you have shown here you don't have a cyclic dependency.  Does Input.h` use `GameObject`?

Comment: This is just my opinion, but "cyclic dependencies" and "coupling" don't matter as much in game code as it is in other software code, including game engine code.

A game's code is usually either thrown away or reused entirely, it's rare that you have this object that just works for another game as standalone.

Otherwise, I guess your other solution would be to store an abstract IGameObject pointer in your Input class (or a GameObject concept once those come out)

Comment: @KABoissonneault it matters alot. Speaking from experience working on games that have radically changed scope over a 2-3 year period and not taken these things into account, makes the code base a nightmare. And lots of code gets reused between games.

Comment: @messy You aren't showing a cyclic reference. Input should be easy to keep separate from the GameObject, unless you are baking in callbacks right into the input mechanism, if that's the case you might want to think of another way to deal with events of this sort, however if the scope of you game is small, a cyclic isn't going to cause so much issue, I would say don't use them until you have to.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes it does. It work with the `GameObject` instance and manipulate it.
@PhilCK `Input` changes the velocity vector of the `GameObject` and simalar regarding movement

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using raw pointers (personally I think this is a bad idea), so I see no problem in having this cyclic reference, just remember to check for null.

If you were using smarter pointer types, in this case you would use a strong reference in one direction (the one that "contains" the other) and a weak reference in the other (the one that only needs a way to communicate).

For example, your game object probably owns the input mechanism; but the input mechanism just needs a way to communicate the input to the game object.

> std::weak_ptr is used to break circular references of std::shared_ptr.

See:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr

Also, check if your input really needs a hold on the whole game object, or just *some object that has certain interface*. In that case, event mechanisms or the delegate pattern could help you remove some hard dependencies.

Comment: I'm using Null object to avoid checks for null.

Answer (score 0):

**Cyclic references or two-sided reactivity is not uncommon.**

For example, say we have a client/server relationship. Based on changes on the client or the server for, say, a webapp, the server can decide to update the client, or the client can forward an activity or action that the user has taken that requires a client's response. Either way, both might have a reference to the same data or to each other, which requires "references..." or do they? Sometimes, it can be more helpful to decouple the references from the interface to modify the data pointed to by the references.

The general response for this, much like web communications, is asynchronous I/O or message passing, and this is not an unusual pattern in even a game--often times, single-player games can make use of the message-passing model (think SimCity's GlassBox simulation with "agents" or MMORPGs with actual networking messages/packets).

**If you're concerned about "coupling," perhaps you should consider various async techniques to prevent classes from having built-in callbacks to other modules that require their definitions**; callbacks/reactor functions are a very common occurrence--Boost.Signals2 has a nice example of how this might be used, as well as `std::async`, I believe. Another option is to simply abstract everything with message passing, much like peer-to-peer networking, and encapsulate each module of your engine with message-passing/receiving modules. This would also make diagnostics easier to implement, provided an external module could "peek" at the metadata of messages.

Comment: Okay. For my `GameObject` class I'm heavily using the _Component pattern_. So I've to live with the two-sited reactivity? The main problem I see is if there are changes for the `GameObject` it will affect the `Input` class directly which is against good software design.